# Function in function not returning array

Tags: php, arrays

This function should iterate through multidimensional array and return collection of array's `element_rule_id` values. Hovewer it's not returning anything.

You can check var_dump of array here: http://pastebin.com/T5nwGmna

```
function deepIns($array = array(), $collect = array(), $str = '') {
    $count = count($array);
    foreach($array as $i => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            if(array_key_exists('element_rule_id' ,$val)) {
                $collect[$val['element_rule_id']] = 1;
            }
            if(($count - 1) == $i) {
                if(array_key_exists('0', $val['condition'])) {
                    deepIns($val['condition'], $collect);
                }
                else {
                    return $collect;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Expected result would be:

```
array (size=5)
  'rule_demo_rules1_1' => int 1
  'rule_demo_rules1_2' => int 1
  'rule_demo_rules1_3' => int 1
  'rule_demo_rules1_5' => int 1
  'rule_demo_rules1_6' => int 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In desining of recursive functions, returning is ambigous way, simple solution is to put your function in an static class, and add the return results into that class:

```
class xx {
public static $result;
function deepIns($array = array(), $collect = array(), $str = '') {
    $count = count($array);
    foreach($array as $i => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            if(array_key_exists('element_rule_id' ,$val)) {
                $collect[$val['element_rule_id']] = 1;
            }
            if(($count - 1) == $i) {
                if(array_key_exists('0', $val['condition'])) {
                    deepIns($val['condition'], $collect);
                }
                else {
                    self::$result[] = $collect;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: That didn't helped, I'm still getting NULL

Answer (score 0):

All is needed was $collection before `deepIns($val['condition'], $collect);`

```
$collection = deepIns($val['condition'], $collect);
```